# Get common rows in two Data tables

Tags: c#, datatable, interaction

I have a table `PromotionRequest` with 4 columns:

```
| PromoId | PromoType 
----------------------
|   101   |  1   |  
|   101   | 2    |  
|   103   | 3    |  
|   104   | 4    |
```

I have a table `PromotionResponsek` with 4 columns(`PromoId`,`PromoType` ,`Value`,`PromoDesc`) one of which is `PromoId`

I have to find all the rows in `PromotionResponse` whose `PromoId` value matches with `PromoId` value of `PromotionRequest` Table.

Comment: Are PromotionResponse and PromotionRequest both in you database? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have a solution where  I have to run a for loop(no. of rows in PromotionRequest  ). Set expression ="PromoId='" + dtPromotionRequest  .Rows[i][0] + "'"; and pass this expression in 2nd data table.
But I don't want to run a loop.

Comment: Could you paste in the code for it so we can see what you are doing so far? How do you want to do it? Using LINQ maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var matched = from table1 in PromotionRequest.AsEnumerable()
               join table2 in PromotionResponse .AsEnumerable() on
               table1.Field<string>("PromoId ") equals table2.Field<string>("PromoId ")
               where table1.Field<string>("PromoId ") == table2.Field<string>("PromoId ")
               select table2;
if (matched.Any())
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have tagged this with SQL so if you want to perform this in SQL, then you will use an `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
select rs.promoid,
  rs.promotype,
  rs.value,
  rs.promodesc
from PromotionResponse rs
inner join PromotionRequest pr
  on rs.promoid = pr.promoid
```

Comment: Downvoter care to explain?  This was tagged with SQL as well as C#.  The user did not state they do not want a SQL answer.

Comment: @PranayRana if the user specifies that they want a C# solution only, then I will delete but they tagged it as both so I feel this is still an appropriate answer.

Comment: I did not tag SQL , the person who formatted my question added sql tag.
Any ways thanks for the effort.

Comment: @palakmehta got it, I saw the SQL tag and figured I would add a sql only answer.

Comment: @palakmehta that doesn't mean you shouldn't be doing this in the more efficient place (SQL Server). The current selected answer pulls the entire tables down and then discards the rows it doesn't want - this seems quite wasteful to me.

Answer (score 4):

you can try out this linq way to find the id in response table like as below

```
List<int> ids = requesttable.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(r => (int) r["Id"])
               .ToList();


var query = from item in responsetable.AsEnumerable()
            where ids.Contains( (int) item["Id"] )
            select item;
```

Comment: PromoId  is stored as string in DataTable.

Comment: @palakmehta - you can use string type insted of int ...i m not sure that , it will give you proper result

Comment: So the person who down-votes a more efficient SQL answer (and makes a pointless and incorrect edit to that answer) suggests Linq without knowing if the OP is already using Linq or has any idea what it is. Interesting.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I m not getting you but as per op in above answer comment that sql tage is added by some one else not by op..and from C# tag and after reding descrip-tion of question which uses data table i provided my answer for it ...